# Found error creating instance using Vultr-cli API

Tags: api, rest, command-line-interface, vultr

I tried putting the code as mentioned in the documentation and I received an error.

```
vultr-cli instance create --region ewr --plan vc2-1c-1gb --os 148 --label my-instance --ipv6 false
```

**error creating instance : {"error":"Cannot add instance. Specified os_id not available","status":400}**

[image]

Comment: Where did you get 148 for your OS value?

Comment: @john-glenn I believe got that value from Vultr documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Vultr documentation does contain OS ID's, but it also warns:

> Do not rely on the OS or Plan IDs listed in this guide; use the appropriate endpoint to retreive values...

Run `oslist` from the CLI and select an ID from the response. [Here](https://github.com/yikaus/vultrcli) is a link to the documentation for the CLI if you need help running the oslist command.

Comment: Tried and this happened... PS C:\Users\PC> vultr-cli oslist
Error: unknown command "oslist" for "vultr-cli"
Run 'vultr-cli --help' for usage.
unknown command "oslist" for "vultr-cli"
PS C:\Users\PC>

Comment: Is there a similar command if you run --help?

Comment: This is the working command: vultr-cli os list

Comment: Are you able to confirm the OS ID?

Comment: Yes of course, now I would like to know how to create a number of quantities in a single command and how to delete all the instances in a single command.

Comment: Okay. Let's mark this question as closed and search for an existing post about multiples (and make a new one if there isn't already an answer).

Comment: The link provided above is *NOT* the vultr-cli as provided by Vultr. It is a third party link. The proper CLI is:

https://github.com/vultr/vultr-cli

not

https://github.com/yikaus/vultrcli

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found to create an instance via Vultr-cli.

```
vultr-cli instance create --region ewr --plan vc2-1c-2gb --os 371 --label my-instance --ipv6 false
```